# Finding the row with the highest number that also matches the ID in an SQL database using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, node-modules

So for this purpose, I have a database that is structured as shown below:

```
╔═════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ Name║ ValueForName ║ Num  ║
╠═════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  A  ║ Jeff Atwood  ║ 5636 ║
║  A  ║ Geoff Dalgas ║  120 ║
║  A  ║ Jarrod Dixon ║  340 ║
║  B  ║ Joel Spolsky ║  959 ║
║  B  ║ Mark Brenna  ║ 7389 ║
║  B  ║ Anth Daverse ║  148 ║
║  C  ║ Ann Jefferse ║  101 ║
║  C  ║ Bonita Thorn ║  959 ║
║  C  ║ Bella Johnss ║  959 ║
╚═════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

The goal is to be able to find the person with the highest number in their specific category.  So I want to find the person with the highest number in the "A" name group, the person with the highest number in the "B" name group, and the person with the highest number in the "C" name group.  So in this database, the highest in the A group is Jeff Atwood, the highest in the B group is Mark Brenna, and the highest in the C group is a tie between Bonita Thorn and Bella Johnss.  In the case of a tie it would just pick the most recent one.
Now I am trying to write some NodeJS code that will perform a query on this database to produce the output of an array that looks like:

```
people = ("Jeff Atwood", "Mark Brenna", "Bonita Thorn")
```

As you can see the people with the highest number are put into the array.
I was thinking of doing something like

```
const PLLNames = ["A", "B", "C"];
var sql = "SELECT ValueForName FROM database WHERE Name= " + con.escape(PLLNames[index]);
```

And then just looping through that, but this code has no way of actually finding the highest number.

Does anyone have any idea how I would go about building something like this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you want ties:

```
var sql = @"
    SELECT t.*
    FROM   databaseTable t
           JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               groupLetter
             , MAX(ValueForName) AS maxValueForName
        FROM   databaseTable
        GROUP BY groupLetter
    ) a ON a.groupLetter = t.groupLetter
           AND a.maxValueForName = t.ValueForName;
 ";
```

In your sample data there is a tie between two names in group C so they would both be returned.

Results:

```
groupLetter fullName    ValueForName    
A   Jeff Atwood      5636   
B   Mark Brenna      7389   
C   Bella Johnss      959   
C   Bonita Thorn      959
```

If you want a tie breaker based on alphabetical order of names then you could do this:

```
SELECT groupLetter
     , fullName
     , ValueForName
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.groupLetter
           ORDER BY t.fullName) AS rowNum
    FROM   databaseTable  t
           JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
               groupLetter
             , MAX(ValueForName) AS maxValueForName
        FROM   databaseTable 
        GROUP BY groupLetter
    ) a ON a.groupLetter = t.groupLetter
           AND a.maxValueForName = t.ValueForName
) b
WHERE  rowNum = 1;
```

Results:

```
groupLetter fullName    ValueForName
A   Jeff Atwood      5636
B   Mark Brenna      7389
C   Bella Johnss      959
```

Otherwise, if there is another column to determine who reached that value first then you could use that.